# How to disable cronjob through python

Tags: python, cron

Is there a more "elegant" python solution to disabling cronjobs and enabling cronjobs for a specific user rather than going into the file itself and adding "#" to the start of the line, and then removing them? My intentions is to have a python script take care of deploying some services, but to do so, I must turn off the cronjob for that particular user until the deployment is finished. Of course, I could always do it manually, disable the cronjobs, and then enable them once I'm done, but I'm trying to fully automate this through Python.

If possible, I would also like to avoid having to install additional packages (restrictions set by the owners of the boxes)

Answer (score 2):

You can use libraries such as [python-crontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab). There might be other libs, this one is first I have found.

Comment: Ah, while this solution may be beautiful to implement, I must add that I am not authorized to install packages :( Will edit my question to inlcude this requirement.

Comment: it's not documented but you get a CronItem using cron.find_xxx(), then cronitem.enable(False) and cron.save()